# How do I install context modules in the ubuntu distribution of ConTeXt

Tags: context, ubuntu

Tonight, right before I started trying to compile my dissertation, ConTeXt ate itself. I have determined that the maintained version of ConTeXt in the ubuntu distribution is of appropriate vintage to probably work.

My only problem is that I use the "simplefonts" module and I'm not sure how to install it within the ubuntu context.

What mechanisms exist for adding third party modules to this distribution of ConTeXt?

Comment: Aren't Ubuntu packages based on Texlive? If so, does ubuntu provide some means of calling `tlmgr`? Otherwise, you can consider installing **ConTeXt standalone** in a parallel tree. See [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Ubuntu_installation) for details.

Comment: For this problem, I couldn't run the current version of ConTeXt standalone because I was trying to work around a bug where the equivalent of includes weren't being recognized. My answer though shows my final fix.

Comment: I was trying to answer your original question was "How to install third party modules in ConTeXt in ubuntu". If what you want is to install an older version of ConTeXt, please appropriately modify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't (I think).

Instead, use reverting to an [older installation with the standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Reverting_to_an_older_installation) to go back to an earlier version that might work.

Use: `sh ./first-setup.sh --context=2011.05.18 --modules="t-simplefonts"` to revert and install the module. you can't use the module command without the context otherwise the update occurs magically.

Alternatively: don't use simplefonts and just do fonts the hard way.

Comment: I would love it if someone gave a better answer or something. But this is what my research indicates?

Comment: it is unlikely that there will a better answer from one of the ConTeXt people, some Ubuntu expert is needed for the full question.