# How I do install context modules in the Windows distribution of ConTeXt?

Tags: installing, context, windows, winedt, modules

I know this question almost equal [How do I install context modules in the ubuntu distribution of ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49464/how-do-i-install-context-modules-in-the-ubuntu-distribution-of-context), but I don't understand it and there are simple way  install context modules in the Windows distribution of ConTeXt and I can running ConTeXt with WinEdt 8 without modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the stand-alone-version of ConTeXt?
Under windows, the standard installer is a .bat-file, not a .sh-file. You can run the windows-installer like this: `first-setup.bat --modules=all` as described here: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Command_line_method

You find it in the root directory of ConTeXt, one level higher the `\tex\`-folder or in this archive http://minimals.contextgarden.net/setup/context-setup-mswin.zip

Comment: I can't running first-setup.bat --modules=all

Comment: Which error message do you get?

Comment: I open command prompt and type " first-setup.bat --modules=all, and error message is first-setup is not recognized as internal or externel command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @HirWanto Make sure that you are in the right directory, i.e. the one where `first-setup.bat` is.

Comment: @karlkoeller first-setup.bat in c:\context\first-setup.bat but i running first-setup.bat in C:\Users\hirwanto> , How change directory so I can running first-setup.bat ?

Comment: `cd..` `cd..` `cd context`

Comment: what is cd context ?

Comment: Three command lines to change the path from `C:\Users\hirwanto` to `c:\context\ ` Then you are in the right directory and enter `first-setup.bat --modules=all`

Comment: @karlkoeller,@Hanseat , succes ,